# Creating complex tables with multicolumn on different lines on latex

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

Can someone help me creating this table, I can't figure out how `\multicolumn` work.
I can get to the first two rows of the table but no further. Please help.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show us the code you have so far? You need to specify 18 columns in the table, using `\multicolumn` for the two first rows.

Comment: Also, a tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a `tabular` environment, you need to specify a column for each column in the most populated row.  Then, where necessary, you can combine multiple columns together using the `\multicolumn` command.

The `tabular` should end up looking like this, with a total of 18 columns:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*{18}{c|}}  % repeats {c|} 18 times
\hline
\multicolumn{9}{|c}{k-means clustering} & \multicolumn{9}{|c|}{Fuzzy c-means clustering} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c}{50 clusters} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{60 clusters} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{70 clusters} & 
\multicolumn{3}{|c}{50 clusters} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{60 clusters} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{70 clusters} \\ \hline 
CJ & HT & SVD &CJ & HT & SVD &CJ & HT & SVD &CJ & HT & SVD &CJ & HT & SVD &CJ & HT & SVD \\ \hline
 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: tabular]

Edit:

To use this in (one example of) a typical two-column environment, you would want to use the `\begin{table*}` environment, which allows the table to float across the two columns.  Note that it will necessarily have to be place on the next page from where you call it, so you might have to make the call to the table earlier in the code than where you want to actually refer to it.  This example uses the `IEEEtran` class to illustrate:

```
\documentclass[]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum} % Dummy Text

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\maketitle

\section{A Section}
\lipsum

\begin{table*}
\caption{The Caption}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{18}{c|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{9}{|c}{k-means clustering} & \multicolumn{9}{|c|}{Fuzzy c-means clustering} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c}{50 clusters} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{60 clusters} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{70 clusters} & 
\multicolumn{3}{|c}{50 clusters} & \multicolumn{3}{|c}{60 clusters} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{70 clusters} \\ \hline 
CJ & HT & SVD &CJ & HT & SVD &CJ & HT & SVD &CJ & HT & SVD &CJ & HT & SVD &CJ & HT & SVD \\ \hline
 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\section{A Second Section}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

It appears as:

[image: page1]
[image: page2]

Comment: Alternatively you can use `\begin{tabular}{|*{18}{c|}}` for a more compact column definition.

Comment: Indeed, forgot about that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.cslstr, one more question, I dont want to use the landscape mode to put this table. I want to put this on a two column paper such that the table spans the two columns. Using \begin{table*} will be sufficient or not for a long table like this?

Comment: See my edit.  The important thing is the `\begin{table*}` environment; it should work with any two-column format, so long as your font sizes don't expand the table so much that it goes outside the given margins.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I am using the \documentclass{intech-journal}. The table is constrained to the left. I cannot add picture in the comment. Shared it on dropbox. Thanks.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wn8qa858htu5q7u/texquestion.jpg

Comment: I added the .cls file and a sample pdf generated here https://www.dropbox.com/sh/akjv0uqg9kvbx0r/JGtn49jTta

Comment: I you prefer you can generate quickly create a complex LaTeX tables online with our generator http://www.tablesgenerator.com/.